# Assig multiple columns in a case statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

Hi is there a way of assigning multiple columns in a case statement?

I am trying to assign two columns of data from a case statement on another column,

```
SELECT 
  [FileName],
  CASE 
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5) + '/' + 'ABTA' AS nvarchar(100))
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE '%Adhoc%' THEN CAST([FileName] + ' ' + [SheetName] + '/' + 'FileSheet' AS nvarchar(100))
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'AdvantageData%' THEN CAST([SheetName] + '/' + 'Sheet' AS nvarchar(100))
  END AS ABTA_LookUp
```

this works but it puts

```
   FileName SheetName/FileSheet
```

or

```
   SheetName/Sheet
```

or

```
   89765/ABTA
```

into ABTALookUp

I would like it to split these values out and place into seperate columns in the same statement if possible i.e

```
    ABTALookUp = FileName SheetName
    ABTASource = FileSheet

    ABTALookUp = SheetName
    ABTASource = Sheet

    ABTALookUp = 89765
    ABTASource = ABTA
```

Comment: The CASE expression doesn't work that way. Please read [Dirty secrets of the CASE expression](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression).

Comment: @AaronBertrand In your article I notice that you use `StatusLabel = CASE...` instead of `CASE...END AS StatusLabel`. Is this just a preference, or is there any other reason to use the former syntax? I thought using `AS` was the ANSI way, and that using `=` was just for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @jpw This is all subjective. [`=` is the more readable way, IMHO](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases), though my opinion is not popular. Trying to adhere strictly to ANSI is really pointless, especially if there is no risk of switching platforms, and at the cost of readability. Though I do lean that way when it is indifferent in terms of readability (e.g. I prefer `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` over `GETDATE()` and [`<>` over `!=`](https://sqlblog.org/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or)).

Comment: @jpw For me I am much more often scanning for column aliases than for the expressions. So it doesn't make much sense to put the alias last, and in a position where it is guaranteed to *not* line up from line to line. Even if you don't read [my post](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) and all the comments, at least [look at this graphic](https://sqlblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/bh_as_queries.png) which should illustrate my point - I'll race you to find the expression that yields `TaxPercent`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did read your post :) And I do agree that it's more readable, and that standards adherence maybe isn't a big issue here, in any case writing a tool to change from one style to the other would probably not be too hard, even though parsing SQL can be...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample desired output isn't all clear in my opinion, but maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT 
  [FileName],
  CASE 
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5) AS NVARCHAR(100))
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE '%Adhoc%' THEN CAST([FileName] + ' ' + [SheetName] AS NVARCHAR(100))
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'AdvantageData%' THEN [SheetName] 
  END AS ABTALookUp,
  CASE 
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_%' THEN 'ABTA' 
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE '%Adhoc%' THEN 'FileSheet'
    WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'AdvantageData%' THEN 'Sheet' 
  END AS ABTASource
```

Answer (score -7):

I DID THIS INSTEAD THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

```
    INSERT INTO ABTA_LookUp
    SELECT  [FileName]
    ,CASE   WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'ATE_%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING([FileName],5,5)+ '/'+ 'ABTA' AS nvarchar(100))
            WHEN [FileName] LIKE '%Adh%' THEN CAST([FileName] + ' ' + [SheetName] + '/' + 'FileSheet' AS nvarchar(100)) 
            WHEN [FileName] LIKE 'Adva%' THEN CAST([SheetName] + '/' + 'Sheet' AS nvarchar(100))
            END AS [ABTA_LookUp]
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
    FROM  dbo.BOOK

    UPDATE ABTA_LookUP
    SET ABTASource = 

    (
CASE    WHEN CAST(CHARINDEX('/FileSheet',[ABTA_LookUp],5)AS nvarchar) >1 THEN 'FileSheet'
        WHEN CAST(CHARINDEX('/HQABTA',[ABTA_LookUp],5)AS nvarchar) >1 THEN 'HQABTA'
        WHEN CAST(CHARINDEX('/ABTA',[ABTA_LookUp],5)AS nvarchar) >1 THEN 'ABTA'
        WHEN CAST(CHARINDEX('/',[ABTA_LookUp],5)AS nvarchar) >1 THEN 'HQABTA'
        END 
    )

UPDATE ABTA_LookUp          
SET DEL_SRT_PNT = CHARINDEX('/',[ABTA_LookUp],1)

UPDATE ABTA_LookUp
SET [ABTA_LookUp] = SUBSTRING([ABTA_LookUp],1,[DEL_SRT_PNT]-1)
```

Comment: Why an insert and then an update, when you could just use two case expressions in the single insert statement, like in the answer by jpw?

Comment: This is not the complete list in the case statement it is over 50 lines long so didn't want to over load just wanted an idea of if it was possible 

my way copies the data into lookup and then split lookup into source on / then delete source from lookup

Comment: (Also, it's a really, really, REALLY horrible idea to cast as nvarchar without length. Please [read this article](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx) as it's not something that is worth repeating over and over again every time someone makes this mistake.)

Comment: Voting is actually contributing to the conversation in a productive way. Especially when an answer is downright wrong and a better answer already exists. This isn't whack-a-mole.